# npm install giving errors : [node version : 16.2.0 and npm version : 7.13.0]

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, linux, npm

The command used : sudo npm install
I am trying to execute this command inside the a specific folder.

The package.json file is as shown:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@branu-jp/v-drag": "^0.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "video.js": "^7.10.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.4",
    "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-pagination-2": "^3.0.8",
    "vue-toastification": "^1.7.8",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^3.8.2",
    "vuejs-paginate": "^2.1.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.21",
    "vuex": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "vue-loader-v16": "npm:vue-loader@^16.1.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
```

I have included parts of the log file which mentioned about the errors.
The logs are :

```
8700 timing build:run:postinstall:node_modules/core-js Completed in 275ms
8701 info run node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
8702 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 5415ms
8703 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
8704 timing command:install Completed in 497508ms
8705 verbose stack Error: command failed
8705 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
8705 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
8705 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
8705 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
8706 verbose pkgid node-sass@5.0.0
8707 verbose cwd /home/mediaworker/damWebWorkPlace/damweb
8708 verbose Linux 5.4.0-73-generic
8709 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
8710 verbose node v16.2.0
8711 verbose npm  v7.13.0
8712 error code 1
8713 error path /home/mediaworker/damWebWorkPlace/damweb/node_modules/node-sass
8714 error command failed
8715 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
8716 error Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/mediaworker/damWebWorkPlace/damweb/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
```

I have included parts of the log file which mentioned about the errors.

```
8717 error gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
8717 error gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
8717 error gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
8717 error gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
8717 error gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/usr/bin/python3"
8717 error gyp verb find Python - executing "/usr/bin/python3" to get version
8717 error gyp verb find Python - version is "3.8.5"
8717 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
8717 error gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.2.0
8717 error gyp verb command install [ '16.2.0' ]
8717 error gyp verb install input version string "16.2.0"
8717 error gyp verb install installing version: 16.2.0
8717 error gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
8717 error gyp WARN EACCES current user ("mediaworker") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/16.2.0"
8717 error gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/tmp/.node-gyp"
8717 error gyp verb command install [ '--node_gyp_internal_noretry', '16.2.0' ]
8717 error gyp verb install input version string "16.2.0"
8717 error gyp verb install installing version: 16.2.0
8717 error gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
8717 error gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 16.2.0
8717 error gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /tmp/.node-gyp/16.2.0
8717 error gyp verb created nodedir /tmp/.node-gyp
```

I have included parts of the log file which mentioned about the errors.

```
8717 error make: *** [binding.target.mk:133: Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
8717 error gyp ERR! build error
8717 error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
8717 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/mediaworker/damWebWorkPlace/damweb/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
8717 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
8717 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
8717 error gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-73-generic
8717 error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/mediaworker/damWebWorkPlace/damweb/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
8717 error gyp ERR! cwd /home/mediaworker/damWebWorkPlace/damweb/node_modules/node-sass
8717 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
8717 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
8717 error gyp ERR! not ok
8717 error Build failed with error code: 1
8718 verbose exit 1
```

I have included parts of the log file which mentioned about the errors. Any help would suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending quite some time on this issue, the solution that worked for us was that **"node-sass" was not yet compatible with node v16**. Hence, after downgrading node version from v16 to v14, and downgrading npm from v7 to v6, it worked.